# WinCE Active Sync Debugging Setup

Tags: c#, windows-ce, activesync

Working with Visual Studio 2005 and Windows CE 6.0 R3. I have active sync working, and I am able to deploy my application onto the device through Visual Studio. However, I get system lock ups on the device and the only debug message that I receive is:

```
The thread 0x50c0006 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

A clean exit also prints out an extra line stating the .exe also exited with a code 0.

I feel like there is some obvious step that I am missing or something that is not possible, but have not had any luck with anything I've looked through or tried so far.

Appreciate any information anyone has to offer.

Comment: What are you doing that causes your device to lock-up? And is this scenario reproducible in the Device Emulator? (Also, try using VS2008).

Comment: Have you tried *not* using ActiveSync, but instead using CoreCon?  It's way more stable.

Comment: Opening a second form. I'm thinking it has something to do with memory, but cannot say for sure that is actually the problem. Will look into CoreCon and give it a try. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Got Active Sync working. It was an issue with the service pack not being up to date. Work computer with software installed before I started working so I had assumed everything like that would have been done. Looked at CoreCon and will probably switch to that. Had another suggest that as well today. Thanks again for your responses.